# How to insert column name of one table to row of another table with some added property

Tags: sql-server

Suppose i have a table A with columns :

```
| Name | IsNUllable  | Datatype |
```

And another table B

```
 | id | Stock | Power
```

i want to make an entry to a table A by taking the column Name of Table B and adding property to it
example:

```
| Name | IsNUllable  | Datatype |
|  id  |  False      | int      |
|Stock |  False      | float    |
|power |  False      | nvarchar |
```

Comment: Why create your own table to store this at all? All this information is in the `sys` objects.

Comment: i just want to insert the table b column name to table A row with some added property. Please help if you can. i have to make this for further use.

Comment: But again, why store the information in a table at all, when it's all readily available with the most current information. What is the end goal here? What are you then going to do with that data in `TableA`?

Comment: Sorry sir, but i just want to learn the queries that's all. If turning out to this platform being a learner is a crime than i m sorry.

Comment: And we can show you what the queries you want are, but like I mentioned, the problem you want to solve and the problem you've asked about appear to be quite different (It's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)). What I want to know is what *X* is.

Comment: how come its different ? I just asked the problem. solving the end goal is step by step process for a beginner so far this is my end goal to achieve so please if you can help please help.

Comment: I avoid chats, @youngTalent ; they tend to result in "free consultancy". If you have something new to ask, ask a new question. If you now realise this *is* an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), then you also now need to ask a new question; due to the existence of my answer. If you don't understand my answer, post a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to store this information, it's already available in the `sys` objects. You can easily get this with a query like below:

```sql
SELECT c.[name],
       c.is_nullable,
       t.[name] AS Datatype
FROM sys.columns c
     JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourTable');
```

Comment: no that solves my problem. and its not xy problem for me. but i just want to know or probably an explanation on this part  c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourTable') are these in built property of sys